# What is the maximum number of HTTP redirections allowed by all major browsers?

Tags: web, max, http-redirect

I am designing a web site, spread across many servers, and there are pages where I need up to chain up to 4 redirections in a row.  I tried a few browsers (firefox, chrome, IE) and it seems to work fine.

Apparently, Firefox's default limit is 20 redirections in a row, Chrome's default seems to be 20, and IE8's limit seems to be 10 redirections.

What is the maximum number of HTTP redirections allowed by all major browsers?  Is it 10?

**Edit**:

Why do I need 4 redirections? Basically, the user is in a hotspot, she tries to go to (say) google.com, there is a local captive portal that captures the request and redirects (#1) the user to a local server.  The local server checks some things about the user, but if it does not have the data locally, it redirects (#2) the user to the central web site.  If the user is already logged in to this central Web site, she gets redirected (#3) to another server (there are different portals depending on the user).  Finally, the server checks the user's rights, and if she has the appropriate rights, there is a final (#4) redirection to the local access controller, in order to get access to the appropriate service.  Believe me, I tried my best to remove redirections, but I cannot see where this can be optimized.

Answer (score 9):

4 redirections should work in all major browsers. However, consider reducing the number to give users a faster experience. Each redirection requires a round trip between the user and the server (and requires creating a new connection, if it's redirecting to a different server). In total, the latency will be significant, likely annoying your users.

Comment: Completely agree that user experience and latency need to be considered. This won't be helped if your also hosting ads or other dynamic content on the pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Most pages have no redirection at all.  There is just one very specific scenario where there can be up to 4 redirections, it will be rare, and I have tried to find solutions to lower that number, I don't think it can be done.  I'll edit the question to add more info about the context.

Comment: 4 could be fairly low for some sophisticated login mechanisms where several servers are (cascaded OAuth e.g. final app > social provider 1 > social provider 2 > social provider 1 > final app callback > final app logged in page).

Answer (score 4):

I also curious about this, but doesn't find info about what is the maximum number of redirection of each browser. So I try to test it by myself using this PHP code to each web browser that I have:

```
<?php
$count = $_GET["c"] ?? 0;
$next = $count+1;
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?c='.$next);
exit;
```

The result is:

- 20 = Firefox
- 19 = Chrome, Opera, Brave, Opera Mini, Puffin, UC Browser, etc (maybe all blink based browser)
- 16 = Safari

---

### Question: What is the maximum number of HTTP redirections allowed by all major browsers? Is it 10?

### Answer: Based on my test the maximum that allowed by all major browser is 16.

---

But I can not test IE/Edge because I don't have a windows OS. As Microsoft Edge use Blink engine, so I think the maximum 19 too.
You can test above code using your own server or [this link](https://redirect.gj.lc)(mine). The last URL query number until show ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error is the maximum redirection.