# 10 internal redirects - can this limit be raised?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, nginx

I have a client running into some 500 errors when using a CDN. These errors indicate that there are too many internal redirects, and our research confirms that. The client does not want to adjust their internal redirects, and wants to address this problem in another way.

Based on my research so far, this seems like a hard cap which is not specific to any one type of web server, and is in place to avoid endless loops. That being said, is there any way to raise this limit - for instance to 20 instead of 10?

Example:

1. Browser >>9 redirects>> Origin 200 page (9 redirects total)
2. Browser >>9 redirects>> Origin gives custom 404 page (+1 redirect for custom 404 - 10 redirects total)
3. Browser >> CDN (+1 redirect from custom rule) >>9 redirects>> Origin 200 page (10 redirects total)
4. Browser >> CDN (+1 redirect from custom rule) >>9 redirects>> Origin gives custom 404 page (+1 redirect for custom 404 - 11 redirects total)

Only example 4 gives a 500 error. Without adjusting the redirect configuration or removing the CDN, is there any way to get around this? (Unfortunately, I cannot provide htaccess for more info on the redirects, my apologies).

Comment: More than 10 redirections in a link-chain error requires an irksome effort for debugging. Even 5 redirections is at the limit of useful with a margin of 2_x_ for lousy design decisions. If you can imagine one scenario that could not be solved with 10 levels of indirection, I'd be willing to change my stance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is the HTTP client who decides how many redirects it is willing to follow. The limitation you see stems from a recommendation originally given in [RFC 2068, sec 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-10.3) and quoted again in [RFC 7231, sec 6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4):

> An earlier version of this specification recommended a maximum of five redirections [...]  Content developers need to be aware that some clients might implement such a fixed limitation.

A rough estimate on how many redirects are going to hit the limit for browsers can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-http-redirections-allowed-by-all-major-browsers). Most browsers allow to configure this limit (e.g. Firefox is exposing the [`network.http.redirection-limit`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.redirection-limit) setting).

Webservers then are a different matter: It appears Apache had the `MaxRedirects` option for the `RewriteOptions` directive between [v2.0.45](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions) and [2.1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions). The [LimitInternalRecursion](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) setting seems to have taken over for this. I've been unable to find an equivalent setting for nginx.

As a final note: If you are really seeing this many *internal* redirects (i.e. redirects that are only performed within the rewrite engine and do not lead to real HTTP redirects immediately), this may be a strong indicator to revise your rewrite rules.

Comment: And adding that internal redirects serve no application logic as they never touch the application.

Comment: I had stumbled across that Mozilla article, but didn't see that it verbosely stated 'internal' redirects, so wasn't sure if it was the doc I was looking for. Appreciate your input on my first SO inquiry :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to impress on the client that you must fix the poor application logic that needs countless internal redirects instead of trying to change every browser on the planet.

## ** EDIT **

Apache apparently has the option to change this server side using `RewriteOptions MaxRedirects` option but I think you will still have an issue with browsers which often suggest your users stop the redirects and bail out ... sometimes even before 10 redirects.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the case, but couldn't find anywhere this limitation was documented, even for specific browsers. Are you aware of any documentation I can provide?

Comment: Just so you know: The `MaxRedirects` option got introduced in [2.0.45](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions) but removed again in [2.1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions).