# Ubuntu: Increase the redirect limit of 10

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

PHP/MySQL/Ubuntu 14.04:

tl;dr and simple question: Is there a way to increase the limit of internal redirects to more than 10? Say..15.

I have a cronjob that checks for open jobs to run every minute. In essence, these jobs create a final PDF using FPDF/mPDF, update records, and send email alerts. The PDFs are combined from multiple sources, as well as created from dynamic HTML output on Lynx. If it were just a long logic sequence with no HTML output, I can put it all in one page. But it requires HTML output to draw the PDF.

That being said, the jobs run in sequence. For example:

- Check for jobs for specific ItemID
- Found a job to run (job #1), redirect to a page using Lynx and finish the job. Once finished, write the next sequential job for that same ItemID (job #2). Redirect Lynx to run the next job

And so on. This loops several times until an item is complete. There's a finite number of jobs an item needs to run. Looks like 12 redirects of the above.

I can simply stop the jobs at each run and wait for the clock to hit 1 minute. But when an item requires 6 jobs, that's 6 minutes. Running them one after the other made it in 15 seconds.

This question might be too localized (I think that's the term). I hope my simple question of "Is there a way to increase the limit past 10" is general enough and helpful if answered.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that altering the amount of redirects is not that easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977377/10-internal-redirects-can-this-limit-be-raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LimitInternalRecursion](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#LimitInternalRecursion) to raise the number of possible redirects.
E.g.:

```
LimitInternalRecursion 20
```

It can be used in the [server config or any virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context), so you have to edit one of the main config files (not .htaccess). In Ubuntu it's probably `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for not simply saying "Fix your code". This helps and after reading up on it should solve the issue.