# Redirect user through multiple domains

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

Does anyone know about the browser's policy about multiple HTTP 302 redirections?

Example in steps:

1. On domain A user clicks on a link and lands on Domain B
2. On domain B he is auto-redirected to domain C
3. On domain C he is auto-redirected to domain D which is the final destination

So basically we have 2 auto redirection happening here **(B => C and C => D)**.

It's not a fraud, serving ads or something, there are just 2 apps in between that are doing some additional processing.

So basically my question is, is this something that browsers would **block**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum number of HTTP redirections allowed by all major browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-http-redirections-allowed-by-all-major-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to block this functionality.

More importantly, doing so would break a very basic functionality that Web Servers rely on. You can expect a lot of websites to just stop working.

At a bare minimum, - all 'www', 'HTTP-to-HTTPS' redirects would stop working.
For example: http://www.yourdomain.com -> https://yourdomain.com

Beyond that, many subpages within websites would stop functioning as well.

So I would not be surprised if Chrome and Firefox developers make it very difficult or impossible to disable Redirects altogether at the browser level.

**Edit:**

But to stop infinite redirect (bug), all browsers set redirect limits.

- Chrome: 20
- Firefox: 20
- Safari: [option to change this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203370)
- [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36041063/8683086)

Comment: There is a maximum amount of redirects a browser can set, [as an example for chrome its 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384474/in-chrome-how-many-redirects-are-too-many). If you exceed that number the browser just stops and shows an error message instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Really appreciate it. I was thinking the same, but this got me a bit unsure https://support.google.com/webtools/answer/7347327 . There is a line saying that auto redirect is treated as abusive. But google docs are always vague ... "content element" part, not sure what they mean by that.

Comment: Auto redirects mentioned there are just ads like ones - without user action. Not the ones like SSO, first load (of course, this will decrease SEO score), and so on.